# Help with counting questions involving coloring

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics

I think I have the right solution to this problem but I want to make sure. I get 3 colorings for the tails, 2 for the connecting point, 10 for the points involved in symmetries in the hexagon, 2 for the last point, and 2 for the eye. This gives a total of 240 possibilities. Is this correct?
[image: The Graph I am referring to]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Here is a slightly different way of looking at it.

The number of colorings up to symmetry is equal to the average number of fixed points of all the symmetries. There are four symmetries:

- Identity: There are $9$ vertices, so $2^9$ ways to color the vertices, and all of these colorings are fixed by the identity.
- $g_1$: There are $2^8$ colorings fixed by $g_1$, since the tail vertices must be the same.
- $g_2$: There are $2^7$ colorings fixed by $g_2$, since both pairs of opposing hexagon vertices must be the same.
- $g_3$: There are $2^6$ colorings fixed by $g_3$.

Therefore, the number of colorings is
$$
\tfrac14\big(2^9+2^8+2^7+2^6\big)=240.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Looks right. The hard part is counting the possibilities for the points involved in symmetries in the hexagon.  In particular, there are 4 cases for 2-black, 2-white: 3 with a black in the upper left, and one with two blacks on the rigrht.